# How to capture login audit information for a user logged into MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to find information (user/pass, IP address of the logged in user) regarding the users who connect to mysql (either programmatically via JDBC driver) or via the command line shell to perform a certain operation. Would like to know, if this information can be obtained via a SQL table.

Comment: Are you looking for users currently logged in, or a history of logins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not directly give a method of tracking logins. However, the `init_connect` system variable can be set to a command to be executed when a new user logs in. You could make use of this to insert the values of `USER()` and `NOW()` into an auditing table.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`SHOW PROCESSLIST` might give you some of the information you required -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html</strike>

Even better than that is the General Query Log -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

But its not enabled by default.....but can be logged to a table !

Comment: This shows the list of current logins and not the history, how do I view the history list?

Comment: @Jason Added to my answer - records history